# How to count the occurrences of certain rows in a column from Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

So I have a dataframe of wildfires in California by county. It looks a little something like:

| Year | Counties | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | Monterey | Soberanes |
|  | Kern | Erskine |
|  | San Luis Bishop | Chimney |
|  | San Bernardino | Blue Cut |
|  | Siskiyou | Gap |
| ... | ... | ... |

I also have some lists of certain counties I'm most interested in.

```
relevant_counties = ['Monterey', 'Kern', ' San Bernardino']
```

If I wanted to see how many wildfires occurred in my list of relevant counties, how would I go about doing that? I have tried `df['Counties'].value_counts()` and it gives me a series with a count for each county, but how do I write a function that will then add the number of wildfires that occurred in a county in my `relevant_counties` list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally filter before counting the values:

```
df.loc[df['Counties'].isin(relevant_counties), 'counties'].value_counts()
```

Unless you plan on reusing the counts with various lists of counties:

```
counts = df['counties'].value_counts()

counts[relevant_counties]

counts[relevant_counties_2]
```

**Note on the spaces**

I notice that you have leading spaces in the list:

```
relevant_counties = ['Monterey', 'Kern', ' San Bernardino']
```

Try to avoid this, if you potentially have those spaces or uncertain case in the data, you can homogenize using:

```
# no leading/trailing spaces
relevant_counties = ['Monterey', 'Kern', 'San Bernardino']

clean = df['counties'].str.strip().str.title() # capitalize each word "Abc Def"

clean[clean.isin(relevant_counties)].value_counts()
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I don't know how I missed that! Filtering the dataframe worked like a charm, thank you so much! And thank you also for pointing out the leading spaces in my list. That's definitely just a typing habit so I'll be sure to adjust that. Thank you for the help!